# IdentityServer4 api forward token to another api

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid

my users use mobile app, this mobile app interact with api, some api functions need to call to another api's.
all my api are require Authorize, should i take the tBearerToken and forward it to the other api's or there is another way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. You need to use a delegation pattern to get a valid token to your backend.

You can forward the token from one Api to another, which makes you reuse a token in both Apis. Or what is the same, both Apis share audience and scopes. Which is not a good practice since you get out of the specification.

Or you can extend your grants by implementing a delegation grant on your Idp where the first Api that has the token exchanges it for another token with a different audience but with all the user information. You can see an example in the [IdentityServer4 documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html#example-simple-delegation-using-an-extension-grant).